# Why am I getting a syntax error on offset_adjusted_list variable?

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, while-loop

My code is showing a syntax error over offset adjusted list variable.  Why is this happening and how can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Hint: count your `(`-s and `)`-s.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket (`)`) on the end of the line `offset = list(int(range(1, 27))`.

Comment: ruakh and jono2906 that worked.  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error Statement -1**: list(int(range(1,27))

You have missed one closing bracket ')' in line offset = list(int(range(1,27))

Even after correction, there is error in code: **range** will return list of values, while **int** takes single numeral value, So **int** should not be use in this case.

**After correction**:  list(range(1,27))

**String Library**

- String library does not have attribute ascii, instead use ascii_lowercase
- Use dir(module) to get list of all the functions supported by module

**Error Statement -2**: offset//2

Arithmetic operations can be applied in value of List, not on List as container

Comment: Thank you that was a good way of looking at it :)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a ")" in the line 3

```
offset = list(int(range(1,27)))
```

also range(1,27) gives you a list of numbers from 1..27 excluding 27.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

also you can on use a int() on a list input. It should be either number or a string.

there is no ascii attribute in string module. it should be ascii_lowercase

```
string.ascii_lowercase

((offset//2)+2)
```

above line should be like this

```
(len(offset) // 2) + 2)
```